# getting http 400 when trying to send data to paypal api

Tags: php, paypal

I have tried everything I can possibly think of, and nothing I do helps. I have even gone so far as to download the sample "Pizza Store" application they have on github. Every time, when I replace the "EndPoint" in the sdk-config.ini with "live" and then put in my clientID and clientSecret, and update the bootstrap.php file with that information, that I get from the "my Apps" section I get the error "Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards."
I am even just using the sample application they provide, and I get that error. I have been searching and searching, and it look slike there are a good 40 different end points, but no documentation on how to use them, how to set them, or anything about it. The only thing I can gather from the sample app is that you can set the "mode" to live in the "setConfig" call, but that just results in the 400 error. I am desperate, I need some help here. I have even emailed their support, and haven't gotten a response. I am trying to help a friend out and get a website up where people can buy things, but this 400 error is driving me insane. Here is a direct copy of my code I am using to try this out...

```
$config = Config::getItem('merchant_settings', 'paypal');
$config = $config['production'];
$sdkConfig = array('mode' => 'live');
$apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret']));
$apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);
$card = new CreditCard();
$card->setType('visa');
$card->setNumber('4446283280247004');
$card->setExpireMonth('11');
$card->setExpireYear('2018');
$card->setFirstName('Joe');
$card->setLastName('Shopper');
$funding_instrument = new FundingInstrument();
$funding_instrument->setCreditCard($card);
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('credit_card');
$payer->setFundingInstruments($funding_instrument);
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal('15.85');
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setDescription('A test purchase');
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
try {
  $res = $payment->create($apiContext);
  $this->set('data' , $res);
} catch(PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  $this->set('data', $ex);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  $this->set('data', $e);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the error I am getting back is...

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"2c61b8ecedfc6"}
```

I don't understand, I am using the exact same code as the sample application. Why am I getting that error. I have gone to that link, no help what so ever. Please, I am begging please help. 
Yes, I realize that card information is fake, but I should be getting a credit card declined error, not a malformed request error. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PHP but I think funding instrument is supposed to an array:

```
"payer":{
"payment_method":"credit_card",
"funding_instruments":[
  {
    "credit_card":{
```

If you create a funding instrument array ($fiArray) of length one, and set the first element to $funding_instrument, and pass the array to $payer->setFundingInstruments(fiArray).

Comment: You are correct, as soon as I changed it to $payer->setFundingInstruments(array($funding_instrument)); it worked perfectly. Thank you sir.